# SQLite Expecting a string as Index Column when dropping a column

Tags: laravel, sqlite, migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class RemoveConstructionDateToOrdersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if (Schema::hasColumn('orders', 'construction_date')) {
            Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('construction_date');
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->date('construction_date');
        });
    }
}
```

When I am migrating this laravel migration on a sqlite database, I am getting 
the following error.

> InvalidArgumentException: Expecting a string as Index Column

Comment: Show your full migration, please.

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem is after hours of poking around. Looks like the doctrine/dbal package cannot rename/handle/drop?! SQLite columns that **already have an index**

So my solution was to NOT make any indexes on columns that get later renamed in the migrations

Of course we do want the indexes to exist in MySQL so here's my solution to it.

```
     Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('commentable_type', 100)->nullable()->after('id');

        //only add index if the connection is mysql
        if(config('DB_CONNECTION') === 'mysql'){
            $table->index('commentable_type');
        }
    });
```

So later when you try to rename the column and using SQLite it works.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite doesn't support multiple calls to dropColumn / renameColumn in a single modification.

Look back through your migration files and separate out the dropColumn / renameColumn into their own modification blocks.